# Build up JSON array from JS array of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

In my code, when the user clicks the 'add' button, the date item is added to a JS array. The problem is when more than 1 item is added, it becomes a string and won't bind to the code behind list type.

I need to build up a JSON array from JS array so it will bind to the code behind list

```
var customStartDates = [];

//below id is a date picker bound to a list type
customStartDates.push( $("#StartDateCustom").val());

//below is my attempt to do what I described but does not work
function updateCustomDates() {
        var customDates = {
            dates: []
        };

        for (var i in customStartDates) {
            var date = customStartDates[i];

            customDates.dates.push({
                date
            });
        }
        $("#CustomStartDates").val(customDates.dates);
       }
});
```

Comment: customStartDates is already an array. why do you need the updateCustomDates() function? what language are you using in your code behind?

Comment: It's a .NET MVC project. customStartDates doesn't bind when I add more than one item. I assumed this was because the JS array seems to become a comma delimited string when more than one item is added..

Comment: is the line customDates.dates.push({ date }) correct? You're pushing objects into your array instead of just a date string.

Comment: how are you pushing the data to c#? can you post your code?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON array". There are arrays, and there is JSON (which is a text format for encoding JavaScript data). So, build up your array, then call `JSON.stringify(arr)` on it.

Comment: Please include your HTML/Razor, what is the element `$("#CustomStartDates")` targets? What do you mean by " customStartDates doesn't bind"? Without ajax there is no real interaction between javascript and the server

Comment: <input asp-for="StartDateCustom" type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" class="form-control" /> .I'm using .net core form helper tags which handle the Ajax posts. StartDateCustom is a List type in the view model which is automatically bound when the form is submitted

Comment: If .net side is a `List<DateTime>` , `input` is probably the wrong HTML element (Tag helper) to use, as it is meant for a single value, not a collection. `$("#CustomStartDates").val(customDates.dates);` sets the value for the HTML element, client side, if the value is a simple array, it''s not surprising the value is being set as a comma delimited string. Also I asked about `$("#CustomStartDates")` not `StartDateCustom` assuming they are different.